Remove document with URL as _id
I want to delete some documents from Elasticsearch.
I used this API DELETE /hiddenservices/_doc/[_id].(hiddenservices is a name of index).
Generally, it worked well, but when the value of _id is a website URL, the API didn't work.
For example, let's say _id of one document is http://blablabla.blabla/.
In this case, the API will be DELETE /hiddenservices/_doc/http://blablabla.blabla/ and never work.
Because I don't have much experience in Elasticsearch, I am not sure how to fix this issue.
Please anyone help me with this...

@Val's answer is absolutely correct. But there is an alternative way if you don't feel like URL-encoding the id. You can simply use _bulk:
PUT hiddenservices/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": "http://blablabla.blabla/"}}
{ "some": "data" }

POST hiddenservices/_bulk
{"delete": {"_id": "http://blablabla.blabla/"}}

If documents were indexing with a custom routing because they have parent/child relationship or the routing was specified during indexing, this routing should be specified as well:
PUT hiddenservices/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": "http://blablabla.blabla/", "routing": "abc"}}
{ "some": "data" }

POST hiddenservices/_bulk
{"delete": {"_id": "http://blablabla.blabla/", "routing": "abc"}}


Thanks for your answer. I have tried second API but got this error.
"type": "json_e_o_f_exception", "reason": "Unexpected end of input: expected close maker for Object ..."

Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

I think 7.10.2.

And how exactly do you run these commands?

Just like from your answer.
POST /hiddenservices/_bulk {"delete": {"_id": "http://blablabla.blabla"}}

Are you using Kibana, postman, something else?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

And the problem turned out to be in a custom routing on the records and not in URL encoding as both Val and I originally thought.

Routing... Then "not found" makes sense, good catch @imotov!!

You simply need to URL-encode the URL that you use as ID and it will work.
When indexing the document, you did it like this:
PUT hiddenservices/_doc/http%3A%2F%2Fblablabla.blabla%2F
{ "some": "data" }

Response:
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_id": "http://blablabla.blabla/",
  "_version": 1,
  "result": "created",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 0,
  "_primary_term": 1
}

And to delete it you need to do the same:
DELETE hiddenservices/_doc/http%3A%2F%2Fblablabla.blabla%2F

Response:
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_id": "http://blablabla.blabla/",
  "_version": 2,
  "result": "deleted",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 1,
  "_primary_term": 1
}


Thanks for your answer. I have tried encoded URL but didn't work and got "not found" response.
